# Remove duplicates in Power Query (BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have retentions agents for an insurance company entering data on a google form. They work on different policies and sometimes capture the same policy twice. There is also a scenario where they would work on the same policy in different months. I would therefore like to remove duplicates that occur in the same month but keep them if they occur in different months. How can I do this on Power Query?

Answer (score 1):

click Select the columns you want to check (policy and month) and then right click remove duplicates

```
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"YourPriorStepNameHere", {"month", "policy"})
```